# Crazy Div:hover sequence flickering/not working in all browsers

Tags: css, html, hover

UPDATE: here is a example of my code below: [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://s225534480.onlinehome.us/stackoverflow.html) Works best in Safari, at least on my comp.

So I'm trying to create a crazy hover sequence (since something was designed without web in mind) but I'm getting crazy flicker when the hovers fire. The hovers kind of work in Safari, but flicker like crazy in FireFox and I have yet to check IE. See my code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <style>
        /* Melon */
        #melon_products1_a {
            position:absolute; 
            width: 140px; height: 220px; 
            top:320px; left: 195px; 
        }
        #melon_products1_a:hover + #melon_products1 {
            display:block; 
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px;
        }
        #melon_products1 {
            display:none; 
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px;
        }
        #melon_products2_a {
            position:absolute; 
            width: 130px; height: 100px; 
            top:535px; left: 275px;
        }
        #melon_products2_a:hover + #melon_products2 {
            display:block; 
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px;
        }
        #melon_products2 {
            display:none; 
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px;
        }
        #melon_products3_a {
            position:absolute; 
            width: 170px; height: 290px; 
            top:250px; left: 330px;
        }
        #melon_products3:hover + #melon_products3 {
            display:block; 
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px;
        }
        #melon_products3 {
            display:none; 
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px;
        }
        #melon_products {
            position:absolute; 
            width: 466px; height: 455px; 
            top:220px; left: 195px; 
            background:url(images/melon/melon_products.jpg);
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="melon_products"></div>
        <div id="melon_products1_a"></div>
        <div id="melon_products1">
            <img src="images/melon/melon_product1.jpg" width="466" height="455" />
        </div>
        <div id="melon_products2_a"></div>
        <div id="melon_products2">
            <img src="images/melon/melon_product2.jpg" width="466" height="455" />
        </div>
        <div id="melon_products3_a"></div>
        <div id="melon_products3">
            <img src="images/melon/melon_product3.jpg" width="466" height="455" />
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've cleaned up your formatting this time, please provide it in a more readable manner next time. It will help us answer your questions more easily. Also consider providing functional examples via http://jsbin.com for faster troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty difficult without images (or a working example), but I think I figured out what you're looking for. I've provided some sample code and a link to an online example.

### HTML

```
<div id="melon_products">
 <div class="hover_product" id="melon_products1"></div>
 <div>
  <div>Product 1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="hover_product" id="melon_products2"></div>
 <div>
  <div>Product 2</div>
 </div>
 <div class="hover_product" id="melon_products3"></div>
 <div>
  <div>Product 3</div>
 </div>
 <div class="default_info">Hover to learn more</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Basic hover effect */
.hover_product {position:absolute;background:rgba(255,255,0,.5);}
.hover_product:hover {z-index:2;}
.hover_product + div {display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:1;width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(255,0,255,1);}
.hover_product:hover + div {display:block;}
.hover_product:hover ~ .default_info {display:none;}

 /* Using this as placeholder for img */
.hover_product > div > div {width:466px;height:455px;display:inline-block;}

/* Product positioning */
#melon_products1 {width: 140px; height: 220px; top:100px; left: 75px; }
#melon_products2 {width: 130px; height: 100px; top:315px; left: 155px; }
#melon_products3 {width: 170px; height: 290px; top:30px; left: 185px; }
.default_info {width:100px;height:150px;position:absolute;right:10px;top:10px;}

/* Wrapper positioning */
#melon_products {position:relative; width: 466px; height: 455px; background:rgba(255,0,0,.5); }
</style>
```

### Online example

- [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4wb5P/6/)

Comment: Hey, I've created an example here:http://s225534480.onlinehome.us/stackoverflow.html

Comment: Thanks, but the images where the mouse rollovers must change as well. Thus they affect all the images since they items in the images overlap...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow--could you explain what you want in more detail?

Comment: s225534480.onlinehome.us/stackoverflow.html So here is my example, check out the images. When you rollover one of the absolute divs (ex - melon_products1_a), they are just empty to capture where the mouse is moving. That div, then activates an image in a div (ex -"melon_products1") to cover up the default background image (#melon_products). Before, melon_products1 was hidden, but when the mouse rolls over melon_products1_a, that image becomes display:block so it covers the background default image (#melon_products). Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: @jgrannis, so, something like my newest edit? I would suggest against extreme changes in background as there will be a bit of flickering, but other than that you can put pretty much anything in the div that appears when hovering over a product (image, text, anything).

Comment: The issue I'm having is that I want the image to change under the hover (and all the other hover hot spot locations). So instead of that absolute hover hot spot changing something on the right that doesn't intersect any other hover hot spot, I want it to affect the whole area (which in hand intersects all other hover hot spots), like my example: http://jsbin.com/educav